# cameraOverlayView of UIImagePickerController disappears immediately

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

My Storyboard contains a CameraViewController in which I designed my custom overlay view.
As long as I use it as one tab of my UITabbarController, the cameraOverlayView is visible. But if I segue to this view controller from any other VC, the overlay view is visible only for a fraction of a second, then only the preview image is visible.

```
@implementation CameraViewController 

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    UIImagePickerController *picker = [UIImagePickerController new];
    if (![UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) return;
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    picker.showsCameraControls = NO;
    picker.allowsEditing = NO;
    picker.cameraOverlayView = self.view;

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I have tried any segue types, presentation styles, etc., the problem stays the same.

I inserted some logs in `viewDidDisappear`, and noticed that this function in fact is called, I guess that's the reason why the overlay disappears.

Keep in mind: If I just open the tab of my Tabbarcontroller, everything just works fine! The problem only occurs if I segue to the CameraVC.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to select modal presentation style and "Over current context", because then the viewDidDisappear event is not triggered.